# vim: cursor not blinking by default

Tags: vim

I installed vim, I opened it, and I found the cursor is not blinking. Is that the behavior by default?

How can I make it blink?

Ubuntu 12.04, vim 7.3.429.

Comment: This sounds like a function of your terminal emulator...

Comment: I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 on virtual box, and then vim on it..is maybe the cause of the problem?

Comment: Does your cursor blink when you're in the shell, before you launch vim?

Comment: So not a vim problem. Check your terminal settings.

Comment: Yes, I had the cursor blinking as false in xterm configuration..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a terminal setting, it has nothing to do with Vim. Many people find a blinking cursor distracting there, that's why it's probably off by default.

When you're working locally on the same box (i.e. without remote access), I would recommend using GVIM, the graphical version of Vim. Though it generally looks and behaves the same as console Vim, it has some nice visual features (like undercurling spell errors), supports some more key combinations for mappings, and avoids some problems with pasting text. In GVIM, you can influence the cursor, cp. `:help 'guicursor'`.

Comment: thanks! I will take a look..any way what do you mean with "influence the cursor,cp"?