# Is it possible to adjust the cursor blink rate?

Tags: vim, text-cursor

Is it possible to adjust the cursor blink rate in the Vim editor (when in normal mode and insert mode)? And if this is possible, how can it be done?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://superuser.com/q/1130567/52365) to Superuser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim: cursor not blinking by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439270/vim-cursor-not-blinking-by-default)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:set guicursor=i:blinkwait700-blinkon400-blinkoff250`

This changes the blinking of the cursor in insert mode (use n-v-i for normal, visual and insert mode). Adjust the times to your needs.

From the documentation `help guicursor`:

> blink times for cursor: blinkwait is the delay before
>               the cursor starts blinking, blinkon is the time that
>               the cursor is shown and blinkoff is the time that the
>               cursor is not shown.  The times are in msec.  When one
>               of the numbers is zero, there is no blinking.  The
>               default is: "blinkwait700-blinkon400-blinkoff250".